# Can't modify SQL Server table structure with encrypted column

Tags: sql-server, always-encrypted

> 'Donors (dbo)' table
>
> - Unable to modify table. Operand type clash: nvarchar(11) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name =
>   'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'Column
>   Encryption Key', column_encryption_key_database_name =
>   'GODonationsDB') is incompatible with nvarchar

I get this error when trying to make any modification to the **structure** of the Donors table. I'm not modifying the encrypted SSN column, but it still happens. I'm trying to change the datatype of a normal date field. This database has been around for awhile. The encrypted field datatype is Nvarchar(11), but maybe years later it is supposed to be varbinary?

Comment: Trigger? Computed column? Temporal? Change tracking / change data capture?

Comment: Also how are you "trying to make any modification" - are you loading the rows up in a grid in SSMS (Edit Top n Rows)?

Answer (score 1):

The `operand clash` error will occur if you're trying to alter a table with Always Encrypted fields using the SSMS table designer or diagram.  Use `ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN` script instead.

Adding new columns: You can only add new columns to the end of a table with Always Encrypted fields -- trying to insert a new column above an existing column causes the `operand clash` error. (You can still use the table designer to add new columns to the end of a table, though.)